# Posting an array()

Tags: php, arrays, forms

If in my form I post a hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userArr" value="Array([0] => 13    [1] => 10    [2] => 12    [3] => 9    [4] => 14    [5] => 11)">
```

Do I keep benefit of an array?

Do I need to call my input name field `userArr` or `userArr[]` ?

---

Solution was as my array already exists:

```
foreach ($userArr as $value) {
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="userArr[]" value="'.$value.'">';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting -1 each time when a french try to speak english. A good way to motivate me.

Comment: You're assuming a relationship between html and php that doesn't exist. The html that the browser sees is just text. The browser cannot tell a PHP array from text.

Comment: Is it better: <input type="hidden" name="dayArr" value="<?php print_r($dayArr); ?>">

Comment: @Francois: I guess it's less the trying to speak english. It's more that this is outlined in the PHP manual already and what you try to do just likely does not work that way. I think that part of the PHP manual is also available in your language (french?).

Comment: The -1 isn't because of your English, which is quite good.

Comment: @Francois It would help if you explain what you want to do with the array in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You'd better do something like, but "User Input Can Never Be Trusted! Not Even When It's Hidden!"

```
<input type="hidden" name="userArr" value="<?= htmlentities(json_encode(array(10, 20, 30), ENT_NOQUOTES); ?>">
```

And server side do this to keep your array:

```
$arr = json_decode(html_entity_decode($_POST['userArr'], ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

The value you are using will be handled as a normal String, so you can't easily convert it back to an array. There are several ways to encode and decode it. Some examples below. You do have to encode it so the quotes will not cause any problems.

1. json_encode / json_decode
2. serialize / unserialize

If you call your input with `[]` you can post an array to the server, but this is when you got multiple input fields with the same name. For example, you got 5 checkboxes if people want to receive mail about different subject. All those subject can have the same input name with `[]` so you got it dynamically handled instead of giving each input a different name.

Comment: Note: a user can change this data however he wants and thus you handle the array as any other user input or face grave security leaks.

Comment: Totaly true, sessions are way safer ! You can never trust user input.

Comment: This gives *a* how, but where's the *why*?

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize the array and then later unserialize it, but better would be to store the data in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Code in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name"userArr" value="<?php echo base64_encode(serialize($userArr)); ?>" />
```

And in the form parser:

```
<?php
$userArr = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['userArr']));
?>
```

Note that the user can change data however he wants and thus you should handle the array as any other user input or face grave security leaks. Again, a session does not have this problem.

Comment: `serialize` isn't guaranteed to output an HTML-safe string. You should probably pass it to `htmlentities`.

Comment: Good point, but base64 is a much better choice (it can also contain non-printable bytes)

Comment: Why is base64 a much better choice?

Comment: Because serialize can output *any* byte, and in ascii/utf-8 the first 31 character (0x00 till 0x1F) are not printable, htmlentities won't help against that. Example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v1k-04u. base64 uses only a small subset of (printable) ascii so its output won't be a problem.